# How to pause every iteration of the loop using sleep?

Tags: perl

Why does the whole process wait for 10 seconds before showing the results in the following code? I was expecting it to show each iteration every 1 second:

```
my @array = (1..10);
for (reverse(@array)){
    print $_, "\t";
    sleep 1;
}
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are [Suffering from Buffering](https://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).  Add this before your for loop to flush the output buffer (refer to `$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH` in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)):

```
$| = 1;
```